# Does Windows 7 XP mode support the Turbo C compiler?

Tags: windows-7, c

Does XP mode in Windows 7 support the Turbo C compiler?

Comment: Who cares. Run a real compiler.

Comment: could you provide a link to said compiler? There seems to be a borland turbo c, but without a version...

Comment: @Journeyman: That's because Turbo C only went up to 2.0. Over twenty years ago.

Comment: erg, so 16 bit?

Comment: 16-bit DOS executables.  So a VDM is required.  And without significant work one can only make DOS programs with it.  Given that the _open source_ [OpenWatcom C/C++/Fortran compiler](http://openwatcom.org/) has _native Win32 executables_ that can cross-compile to DOS if one truly wants to write DOS programs, I'm with M. Vazquez-Abrams when it comes to the utility of Turbo C on Windows NT.  Even the free-of-charge Borland C++ compiler would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, that it should run in XP mode (which is simply an emulated 32 bit Windows XP SP3 instance running in Microsoft Virtual PC), if it runs in a regular 32 Bit Windows system – if it needed direct access to some form of hardware on a physical system it may fail, but otherwise, it should work.

That being said, testing it would be relatively trivial, and you would probably want to do it even if it installed properly.